# udev forgets about tag in custom rule

Tags: udev

I have a rather simple set of custom rules:

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ENV{ID_MODEL_ID}=="0748", ENV{ID_VENDOR_ID}=="05e3", TAG+="my-card-reader"
TAGS=="my-card-reader", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="disk", ENV{ID_INSTANCE}=="0:1", SYMLINK+="sdcard"
TAGS=="my-card-reader", ENV{ID_INSTANCE}=="0:1", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="partition", SYMLINK+="sdcard%n"
```

I'm trying to identify my USB card reader and then give the microSD card well-known names in /dev. This set of rules used to work in 16.04, in 18.04 it doesn't.

When checking `udevadm monitor -p`, I can see that the USB reader is recognized:

```
UDEV  [1832291.742219] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb4/4-2 (usb)
ACTION=add
[…]
SUBSYSTEM=usb
TAGS=:my-card-reader:
[…]
```

But when I check the sysfs path later with `udevadm info /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb4/4-2`, my TAG isn't shown anymore—in fact, there is no `E: TAGS` entry available at all.

For other devices, for example a partition on my microSD card, Ubuntu's default `systemd` TAG remains available:

```
P: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb4/4-2/4-2:1.0/host3/target3:0:0/3:0:0:2/block/sdf
N: sdf
[…]
E: SUBSYSTEM=block
E: TAGS=:systemd:
[…]
```

**Update 1**

I've been running with `udev_log="debug"` while unplugging and replugging the reader and the SD card, suddenly and until now only once, my rules **were** applied. However, looking at the journalctl debug logs from udev and comparing, I cannot see a difference other than the race between kernel log, udev daemon log, and forked udev worker as well as the seq numbers.

**Update 2**

I have pretty much reduced the problem. The tag is available when the USB card reader is attached during boot. When I (re-)attach it later, the tag is missing.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, there is a whole thing going on: https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/7587

Long story short: TAGS are only valid per event and not persisted. Removing `ACTION=="add",` from my rules file made it work

Answer (score 0):

Most probably, that tag was overwritten by another rule.

- Ubuntu 18.04 got updated rules .. Check using `grep -r TAG` in system rules folders, see `man udev`.
- Custom rules file given low number .. Use `udevadm test ...` and `udevadm trigger ...` to verify which rules processed for that event.

Comment: There are exactly two files ordered after my rules (`/etc/…/99-sdcard-reader.rules`): `/lib/…/99-systemd.rules` and `/lib/…/99-vmware-scsi-udev.rules`. When running the test command, my tag is shown.